# Facebook API Permission Page

Tags: facebook, api

Well i want to allow Facebook login on my site. I have created the API and user's can login to the website. But for the first time a pop up comes to the users asking for Permission.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/

Can i just skip the users from this permission page and directly logs them in.

Thanks

Comment: tell what you want clearly do you want to check the login credentials the 1st time the user logs in and upon the subsequent login you dont want to check is it??

Answer (score 0):

Any person must accept the basic permission for getting their Facebook profile data for use in your website

Comment: so it means there is no way we can skip that basic authentication part! thanks